# Disparar função apos alteração no input sem submit

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Bom dia/ Boa tarde/ Boa noite

Eis o meu problema: eu preciso que a medida que o usuário vá digitando no campo minha função seja acionada, sem necessidade de dar um submit. Estou tentando usar o evento change, só que ele só aciona a função depois da mudança de foco daquele campo.

segue o que estou tentando fazer:

`form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {...}`

Então eu gostaria de saber se existe um evento especifico para isso que eu quero,ou algo que funcione assim o evento change.

Grato!

Comment: Olá, Você pode utilizar os eventos de keyup (acionado imediatamente após o usuário tirar o dedo da tecla pressionada), ou keydown (acionado ineditamente após o usuário digitar algo)

Comment: *" medida que o usuário vá digitando "* se o usuário está digitando deve ser um input, textarea, etc... pq está adicionando o evento ao `form`? deveria ser no change do elemento

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o evento ***onkeyPress***('Chama função ao apertar qlq tecla') ou ***onkeydown***('Chama função ao soltar tecla pressionada')
Segue abaixo exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="demo" onkeydown="keydownFunction()" onkeyup="keyupFunction()">

<script>
function keydownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function keyupFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma função parecida com a resposta acima, Segue o codico:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<body onload="alerta()">

 <input type="text" id="campo" placeholder="Insira um valor aqui">

 <script>

   function alerta() {

     alert("Funçao executada com sucesso!")

     document.getElementById("campo").addEventListener("keydown", alerta)

    }

 </script>

</body>

</html>
```